# How to move across empty & filled cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a vba to isolate a specific cell along a row. My code so far has brought me to an active cell, and from here I am stuck.
The cell I need will always be the 3rd non-blank/empty cell along the row. Between the active cell and the required cell are blank cells, and two irrelevant non-blank/empty cells. 
The spacing between them is not fixed so I cannot offset a certain number of cells. 
I have had help to a point but i am now stuck, any help would be greatly appreicated!

```
i = 1
    For Each cell In ws.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cells

    If Not IsEmpty(cell) = True Then i = i + 1
    If i = 4 Then cell.Select: Exit For

    Next cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using ActiveCell & .Select ideally. See if this helps:

```vb
Sub thirdNonBlank()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim C As Long, cnt As Long
Dim rngCellFind As Range

With ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    Set rngCellFind = .Find( _
                        What:="Hello", _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext _
                        ).Offset(1, 0)
End With

For C = 1 To ws.Cells(rngCellFind.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rngCellFind.Row, C)) Then cnt = cnt + 1
    If cnt = 3 Then
        ws.Cells(rngCellFind.Row, C).Select 'I'd advise against using .Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next C
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** changed as per OP new input.

Comment: Thanks for this, by itself it does exactly what i need it to. however I cannot seem to get it to integrate with my coding before it. Any hints or tips on this?

Comment: Set rngCellFind = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Hello", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
 Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    rngCellFind.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select